# How to delete a line break character in list item python

Tags: python, list

I have a small question regarding python lists.
See this code:

```
passwords = []
fob = open("/path/to/file", "r")
for add_items in fob :
        passwords.append(add_items)
print passwords
fob.close()
```

The code result:

```
['Monster1\n', 'Monster2\n', 'Monster3']
```

How to delete `\n` in each `add_items` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `rstrip('\n')` or just `rstrip()`:

```
passwords.append(add_items.rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: You can also just do rstrip() without the "\n" parameter - it defaults to any whitespace if no argument is given, if that works for the asker.

Answer (score 2):

You could clean it up a bit better and remove all surrounding white space by using `strip`. Also, you could simplify things by using a comprehension and a context manager:

```
with open("C:\Users\Bucky\Desktop\pass.txt") as f:
    passwords = [data.strip() for data in f]
```

In this answer, a context manager (the `with` statement) can be learned about [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects). That section should explain more details about the file objects and how to use a context manager.

Comment: There's no need for the `.readlines()` call there - `[data.strip() for data in f]` would be sufficient.

Comment: @twalberg Really appreciate the review. Thanks, you are absolutely right. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension towether with `replace` to clean all instances of `\n` within the string (assuming the password should not contain a carriage return):

```
>>> [pw.replace('\n', '') for pw in passwords]
['Monster1', 'Monster2', 'Monster3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer would work. So would this, without directly stripping each line or using list comprehension:

```
with open("C:\Users\Bucky\Desktop\pass.txt", "r") as fob:
    passwords = fob.read().splitlines()
```